# Call Method From Class or Instantiate Class of an Installed Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is it possible to call a method from a class or instantiate a class which is inside of an installed Eclipse plugin? For instance, my Eclipse plugin includes a class `MyClass`. This class should be used by programmers which have installed my Eclipse plugin. They should be able to instantiate this class and call methods on it. Is this somehow possible?

There is an old page which [explains it related to another product](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rmc/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc%2Fbirt%2Fbirt-22-3.html) (Eclipse BIRT), but the code sample from this page does not seem to work for me:

```
#import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Bundle;
#import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
#import org.eclipse.myCorp.security.Validate;

Bundle mybundle = Platform.getBundle("org.eclipse.myCorp.security");
java.lang.Class validateClass = mybundle.loadClass("org.eclipse.myCorp.security.Validate");
Validate validateInstance = validateClass.newInstance();
String password = validateInstance.getPass(loginID);
```

And it is also always a [problem to import Eclipse packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25446321/719023) like `org.eclipse.core.runtime`, because they usually have multiple dependencies.

So is there a way to do that somehow or is that impossible?

Comment: Code in other Eclipse plugins can use classes in a plugin (provided they are exported). In general normal Java programs cannot use classes in Eclipse plugins.

Comment: Thanks, @greg-449! Would you mind posting an answer with some more information on it? What do you mean by "in general"? Sounds like there is some way to do it?

Comment: I mean a very few plugins can be used out side of Eclipse but the majority cannot.